# Reducer does not call render function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm try to learn and develop React Redux app. In the app I have some private routes. If the user goes to the private routes he should be authenticated with LogIn component and then redirected to the initial route.

The problem is that after the user submits the form and gets authenticated, the reducer doesn't call  the render method of LogIn component.

I'm stuck and can't figure out the reason of this.

// ../ClientApp/src/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Block from './components/Block';
import LogIn from './components/LogIn';

export const auth = {
    isAuthenticated: false
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        auth.isAuthenticated
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
    )} />    
)

export default () => (
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block1' component={Block} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block2' component={Block} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block3' component={Block} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block4' component={Block} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block5' component={Block} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/block7' component={Block} />
        <Route path='/login' component={LogIn} /> 
    </Layout>
);
```

// ../ClientApp/src/components/LogIn.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import './LogIn.css';
import { actionCreators } from '../store/LogIn';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../App';

class LogIn extends Component {
    state = {
        credentials: {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        },
        error: ''      
    }

    dismissError = () => {
        this.setState({ error: '' });
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        const credentials = this.state.credentials;
        credentials[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ credentials: credentials });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.credentials.username) {
            return this.setState({ error: 'This field is required' });
        }

        if (!this.state.credentials.password) {
            return this.setState({ error: 'This field is required' });
        }

        this.props.requestLogIn(this.state.credentials);
    }

    render() {   
        auth.isAuthenticated = this.props.isAuthenticated;

        const { credentials } = this.state;

        if (this.props.redirectToReferrer) {
            const { from } = this.props.location.state || {
                from: { pathname: '/' }
            }

            return (
                <Redirect to={from} />
            )
        }

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div className="panel panel-login">
                            <div className="panel-heading">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                                        <a href="/" className="active" id="login-form-link">Log in</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                            <div className="panel-body">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                                        <form id="login-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                                            {
                                                this.state.error &&
                                                <h3 data-test="error" onClick={this.dismissError}>
                                                    <button onClick={this.dismissError}>X</button>
                                                    {this.state.error}
                                                </h3>
                                            }

                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="username"
                                                    tabIndex="1"
                                                    className="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="E-mail"
                                                    value={credentials.username}
                                                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input
                                                    type="password"
                                                    name="password"
                                                    tabIndex="2"
                                                    className="form-control"
                                                    placeholder="Password"
                                                    value={credentials.password}
                                                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <div className="row">
                                                    <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                        <input
                                                            type="submit"
                                                            tabIndex="3"
                                                            className="form-control btn btn-login"
                                                            value="Log in" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
        redirectToReferrer: state.redirectToReferrer
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(LogIn);
```

// ../ClientApp/src/store/LogIn.js

```
const authenticated = 'AUTHENTICATED_USER';
const unauthenticated = 'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER';
const authenticationError = 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR';

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    redirectToReferrer: false,
    error: '',
    token: ''
}

export const actionCreators = {
    requestLogIn: ({ username, password }) => async (dispatch) => {
        try {

            const response = await fetch('api/Authentication/Authenticate',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    }),
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    credentials: 'same-origin'
                });
            const token = await response.text();

            dispatch({
                type: authenticated,
                token
            });

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            dispatch({
                type: authenticationError,
                error: 'Invalid email or password'
            });
        }
    }
}

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    state = state || initialState;

    switch (action.type) {
        case authenticated:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                redirectToReferrer: true,
                token: action.token               
            };
        case unauthenticated:
            return { ...state, isAuthenticated: false };
        case authenticationError:
            return { ...state, isAuthenticated: false, error: action.error };
    }
    return state;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to [remix23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8520481/remix23)'s answer. He was right that I had several reducers and I had to point *logIn* reducer in the mapStateToProps function like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.logIn.isAuthenticated,
        redirectToReferrer: state.logIn.redirectToReferrer,
        error: state.logIn.error,
        token: state.logIn.token
    }
}
```

Just for your information (perhaps it can be usefull for someone) here's my reducer configuration:

//.. /ClientApp/src/store/configureStore.js:

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import * as Items from '../reducers/items';
import * as LogIn from './LogIn';

export default function configureStore(history, initialState) {
    const reducers = {
        items: Items.reducer,
        logIn: LogIn.reducer
    };

    const middleware = [
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history)
    ];

    // In development, use the browser's Redux dev tools extension if installed
    const enhancers = [];
    const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
    if (isDevelopment && typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.devToolsExtension) {
        enhancers.push(window.devToolsExtension());
    }

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        ...reducers,
        routing: routerReducer
    });

    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
    );
}
```

Comment: Becase *auth* variable always has *isAuthenticated* = false even if Login form was submitted.

Comment: To resolve this problem, in App component you need *connect* to store and get state isAuthenticated from store instead of from auth variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `// ../ClientApp/src/store/LogIn.js` suggests that you may have several reducers defined under the `store` folder.

This usually implies that you also have an "app" reducer (a combination of all your reducers with a key for each of them).

If that the case and the key for your login reducer is `login`, then in the mapStateToProps you provided, you may have to access the isAuthenticated value this way (otherwise state.isAuthenticated will stay undefined):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.login.isAuthenticated,
        ...
    }
}
```

Also as others have suggested, accessing auth from the initial value of your auth store is bad, even if as it looks it may work because you set it in the Login component.

You should connect App like you did with Login and access isAuthenticated through props (and never set a value of the initial states of your stores).